# How would I create a back button for a random generator so the previous textview is displayed?

Tags: android, eclipse, button, random

The question really is that simple. I have an activity with a button that randomly changes the text of a textview box. How do I add another button that gathers the previous number generated so the previous textview text comes back - for a quotes app.Is there a feature I require? I have searched, but I cannot find a feature that will 'go back' on the random number generator.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to go back on the generator itself, just remember the previous values. Store it in a variable. Here we are using prev as an array, because we need it to be final so we can access it in the anonymous inner classes (click handlers). But we also need to change it. So we use the `prev[0]` value.

Here I am assuming you have a button called nextNum which generates the next random number. But that could be anything, it doesnt matter. When you generate a new random number simply update the 0th element of the prev array and you should be fine.

```
final String[] prev = new String[] { "" }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    // ....
    Button BackQuote = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back); 
    final TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    // number generator button
    Button nextNum = (Button) findViewById(R.id.random);
    nextNum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // generate a random number

            // store it in prev
            prev[0] = rndNum.toString();
        }
    });

    BackQuote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v) {
            display.setText(prev[0]); 
        } 
    });
}
```

Unless there is a specific reason you want to avoid this, then this would work perfectly fine. And there is no way to go *back* on a random generator. By definition it IS random! (Yes, Pseudo-random. Nonetheless)

So if you want to keep an history, you are going to have to implement those yourself. I have yet to see a random generator which has a *history* feature. I'd be surprised if i do too.

Comment: Why wouldn't this work then? : Button BackQuote = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
            final TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            BackQuote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            String prev = (String) display.getText();
             public void onClick(View v) {
              
              display.setText(R.string.prev);
             }
           });}

Comment: you can't change the value of a resource string (`R.string.prev`) they are compile time constants. Instead use a local variable string (`display.setText(prev)`). If you need it to persist then you can store it in SharedPreferences.

Comment: How do I get the previous text though?